# How to escape double inverted commas in json values from pandas dataframe for parsing?

Tags: python, json, regex, pandas, escaping

so this is a long question but please hold on as I try my best to explain my problem:

I have a dataframe which has one column with rows as json, and I am able to parse them correctly

```
   id | email     | phone no | details
-------------------------------------------------
0  10 | abc@g.com |   123   | {"name" : "John "Smart" Wick", "address" : "123 c "dumb" road"}
1  12 | xyz@g.com |   789   | {"name" : "Peter Parker", "address" : "L "check" street"}
```

I want this json to be distributed to columns as:

| id | email | phone no | name | address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | abc@g.com | 123 | John "Smart" Wick | 123 c "dumb" road |
| 12 | xyz@g.com | 789 | Peter Parker | L "check" street |

To break the json keys into columns, I am able to do as:

```
# Check: 1
result = df.pop('details').apply(json.loads).apply(pd.Series).join(df)
```

This works always until when I come across a situation like that above where there are inverted commas as part of the json value in any field. This data is for representation purpose in reality I have millions of records and the column 'details' has 10+ key/value pairs.

For a hot fix, this is what I have done:

```
# check: 2
df['details'] = df['details'].str.replace('John "Smart" "Wick','John Smart Wick')
df['details'] = df['details'].str.replace('123 c "dumb" road','123 c dumb road')
df['details'] = df['details'].str.replace('L "check" street','L check street')
```

Then I run the code at #check: 1 and it works fine and replace it again this time the other way around. In a million records, there are just 2 such cases which leads to such a problem breaking the code so I found those 2 notorious records and for a hot-fix replaced the data to remove the inverted commas and later after processing re-introduced them.

What I want is to have a way such that no matter how many times such issues happen it doesn't create a problem and passes #check: 1 easily and return the original value without me having to catch such records manually and replacing it for the thing to run. I was wondering if regex can do this, and I tried few things but those were not good enough and kept throwing error.

I am able to solve the issue at my level but a universal way to handle all such exceptions in json key/value pair for a column in pandas dataframe will be a great thing to learn. I know the json is not clean here so basically a way to clean it for any such scenarios so that we can do the splitting of the key/value into individual columns.

Thanks for any help.

Edit: I have put this in comment also, if I add escape characters then it works fine like:

```
df['details'] = df['details'].str.replace('John "Smart" "Wick','John \\"Smart\\" Wick')
df['details'] = df['details'].str.replace('123 c "dumb" road','123 c \\"dumb\\" road')
df['details'] = df['details'].str.replace('L "check" street','L check \\"check\\" street')
```

This will work too but it still requires me to identify the records manually and add a replace command for those records with escape characters. Can this be done in a loop for the entire 'details' column to self-identify such cases and add escape characters wherever required?

Comment: I am doing some checks and I found that when I replace the values with \\ as in:
df['details'] = df['details'].str.replace('John "Smart" "Wick','John \\"Smart\\" Wick')
it works and gets the data and I don't have to replace again later. But, how do I introduce the escape characters "\\" for all such cases in a large dataframe where any json value have inverted commas in it?

Comment: If you screwed up when you saved the data, tt re is no sane way to unscrew it. Fix the source you are importing from.

Comment: It is not that I have control over the source system. Those are coming from a difference source where it seems people can pass on data with inverted commas in fields which then comes to us in raw format and it is becoming an issue. Is there a way out?

Comment: It looks like the input format is hosed. You can probably sort out the majority of the strings rather easily but there will be corner cases where you just have to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are only two fields in the stringified JSONs, you can use *contextual matching* with regex to make sure you match any text between the two names or end of the string.

Here is the regex you can use to match and capture the necessary bits:

```py
(?s)("(?:name|address)"\s*:\s*")(.*?)(?="(?:\s*,\s*"(?:name|address)"|}$))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/phq0HA/1). The matches contain two adjacent groups where the first one needs to be kept as is, and all `"` chars in the second group should be prepended with a literal backslash.

Use `Series.str.replace` to perform this manipulation:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'text':['{"name" : "John "Smart" Wick", "address" : "123 c "dumb" road"}']}
)

rx = r'(?s)("(?:name|address)"\s*:\s*")(.*?)(?="(?:\s*,\s*"(?:name|address)"|}$))'
df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace(rx, lambda x: x.group(1) + x.group(2).replace('"',r'\"'), regex=True)
# -> df
#                                                                   text
# 0  {"name" : "John \"Smart\" Wick", "address" : "123 c \"dumb\" road"}
```

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor for this amazing suggestion with regex. I knew it will be possible probably with regex but was not sure how. Let me take a look at your suggestion and get back to you.